# how to get data from whoscored

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get data from whoscored.com but when I type this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"
page_html = requests.get(url)
page_soup = soup(page_html.content, 'html.parser')
```

I am gettin page_soup variable as follows

```
<html style="height:100%">
   <head>
  <meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?
SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe frameborder="0" 
height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" 
src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=18&amp;xinfo=10-12988947-
0%200NNN%20RT%281505336855621%20883%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%2077%29%20r%280%20-
1%29%20B15%284%2c200%2c0%29%20U2&amp;incident_id=473000610021824233-
81324132038935514&amp;edet=15&amp;cinfo=04000000" width="100%">Request 
unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 473000610021824233-81324132038935514</iframe></body>
```

Is there any way to get data in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

whoscored.com is using a cloud-based application delivery platform named incapsula that provides security features for webservers in following way:

> Through a simple change to your website DNS records (and with no hardware or software required), your website traffic will be seamlessly routed through Incapsula’s globally distributed network of high powered servers. Incoming traffic is intelligently profiled in real-time, blocking the latest web threats (e.g., SQL injection attacks, scrapers, malicious bots, comment spammers) and thwarting triple-digit gigabit DDoS attacks. Meanwhile outgoing traffic is accelerated and optimized with Incapsula's global CDN, for faster load times, keeping welcome visitors speeding through.

Source: https://www.incapsula.com/faqs/

Your http-request is getting blocked as you can see in the html body:

```
Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 473000610021824233-81324132038935514
```

What you want to do is to bypass incapsula. there exists python module that will help you with that: https://github.com/ziplokk1/incapsula-cracker-py3

I recommend to take a closer look at the [issue #4](https://github.com/ziplokk1/incapsula-cracker-py3/issues/4) because you may have to do some extra work to be able to bypass incapsula.